# Dynamically populated dropdowns in table with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have developed a small interface to list the projects with Django. Each project has multiple versions.
I would like to create a table and in each row I would like to have the following items.

1. Project Name
2. Project Description
3. A dropdown button to select the
   desired version
4. A button to open that specific project and that
   specific version

I am fine with item 1, 2 and 4 but I am struggling to create the dropdown after querying the list of versions.

This is my `project.html`

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Description</th> 
    <th>Version</th> 
 </tr>

 <!-- {% for project in projects %} -->
 <tr>
    <td>{{project.id}}</td>
    <td>{{project.projectName}}</td>
    <td>{{project.projectDescription}}</td>
    <td>{{versionform.as_p}}</td>
    <td><form action="{% url 'builder' project.id %}" method='GET'><button type='submit'>Open</button></form></td>
 </tr>
 <!-- {% endfor %} -->
</table>
```

This is my `model.py`

```
class Project (models.Model):
    
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    projectDescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_by = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectName

class ProjectVersion (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    versionNumber = models.IntegerField()
    versionName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    versionDescription = models.TextField(default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        vName = self.project.projectName + " " + self.versionName
        return vName
```

and this is my `views.py`

```
class ProjectsList(TemplateView):

    template_name = "projects.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'server.share_project')
        query_set = context['projects']
        context['versionform'] = VersionForm
        return context
```

and this is my `forms.py`

```
class VersionForm(forms.Form):
        version_dropdown = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [("version","version1")], label='')
```

Ultimately I will call an API which will load a specific dataset based on Project and ProjectVersion.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: its not django-rest-framework issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out.

So, I changed `forms.py` to be:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, ProjectVersion
from django.shortcuts import render

class VersionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectVersion
        fields = ('versionName', )

    def __init__ (self, project, projectId, projectName, projectDescription, *args, **kwargs):
        super (VersionForm, self).__init__ (*args, **kwargs)
        self.project = project
        self.projectId = projectId
        self.projectName = projectName
        self.projectDescription = projectDescription
        queryset = ProjectVersion.objects.filter(project=project).order_by('-created_at')
        self.fields['versionName'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = queryset, label='', initial = queryset[0])
```

I then changed my `views.py`

```
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProjectsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            queryset = get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'server.share_project')
            context['versionforms'] = []
            for each in queryset:
                form = VersionForm(each, each.id, each.projectName, each.projectDescription)
                context['versionforms'].append(form)
            return context
    ...
```

and finally updated my template as

```
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>{{form.projectId}}</td>
        <td id={{form.projectName}}>{{form.projectName}}</td>
        <td id={{form.projectDescription}}>{{form.projectDescription}}</td>
        <td>{{form.versionName}}</td>
        <td><form action="{% url 'builder' form.projectId %}" method='GET'><button type='submit'>Open</button></form></td>
    </tr>
    ...
```